# files not showing after sqoop import

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

After successfully importing one table from MySql to Hadoop, not able to see any files under hadoop path.
Import command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart:3306/lipu --username root --password cloudera --table student --target-dir =/user/cloudera/jds --m 1
```

It is successful as it is finaly saying the number of records it retrieves.
But when I am checking the contents inside my target directory, it is not showing anything.

```
 hadoop fs -ls  /user/cloudera/jds
```

The above command is not returning anything.
Need your help .

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `=` after `target-dir`.
Try running:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart:3306/lipu --username root --password cloudera --table student --target-dir /user/cloudera/jds --m 1
```

followed by `hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/jds`.